# Cpp file containing WinMain not being compiled

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've a file called AquaMain.cpp

```
#include "AquaGame.h"

using namespace Aqua;

#ifdef _WIN32

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
     AquaGame::get()->init();

     return AquaGame::get()->run();
}

#endif
```

This file is inside a static lib.

When I try to compile a project that uses this static lib the build fails with this error

> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *WinMain@16 referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

The file AquaMain.cpp is not being compiled I don't know why...

If I move the WinMain function to the executable project the function is compiled and everything works, but I would like WinMain to be in the static lib.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you write the prototype of WinMain is AquaGame.h ?

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier there're no references to WinMain in any file... it is just defined in AquaMain.cpp

Comment: Can be [this](http://cipaterson.wordpress.com/2007/09/30/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-_winmain16-referenced-in-function-___tmaincrtstartup/)?

Comment: @Sanz No, this is a window program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though AquaMain.cpp had the extension .cpp Visual Studio 2012 has using it as a header because AquaMain.cpp Property Pages had the "Item Type" field set to C/C++ header.

Changing the field to C/C++ compiler fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare your WinMain as `extern "C"`

```
extern "C" int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
     AquaGame::get()->init();

     return AquaGame::get()->run();
}
```